# How user should automatically activated and go for login?

Tags: login, signup

The theme i am using is WPLMS-Wordpress learning managment system.

When user fill all the details for signup and click on register button. I don't want to activate the user manually I want when user click on register button it automatically activate it's account and go for login.

And the main problem is Every time when user signup I have to go for 
Dashboard USERS->PENDING USER->Activate or DELETE.I want user will automatically activate his/her account.

Help me out.

Comment: Try [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-disable-activation-reloaded/) simple plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in wordpress function `wp_signon`.

```
/// Auto login new user
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $username;
    $creds['user_password'] = $userpass;
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
        if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        echo $user->get_error_message();
```

`$username` and `$userpass` would be posted data from your register form.

Check the [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) for full details.